# Data augmentation in deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

I am working on a deep learning project for face recognition. I am using the pre-trained model VGG16.

The dataset has around 100 classes, and each class have 80 images. I split the dataset 60% training, 20% validation, 20% testing. I used data augmentation (`ImageDataGenerator()`) to increase the training data.

The model gave me different results when I change `ImageDataGenerator()` arguments. See the following cases:

**Case1:**

```
 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')
validate_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
Test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
```

**Case1 result:** High training accuracy and validation accuracy, but the training accuracy is lower. check the following image:

[image: Case1 accuracy]
[image: Case1 loss]

**Case2:**

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True)

validate_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
    Test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
```

**Case2 result:** Overfitting. check the following image:
[image: Case2 accuracy]
[image: Case2 loss]

**Case3:**

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True)

validate_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    Test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

**Case3 result:** High training accuracy and validation accuracy, but the training accuracy is lower.. check the following image:
[image: case3 accuracy]
[image: case3 loss]

1-  Why does using augmentation in validation and testing data `ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)` in case3 give different result than case2?

2- Is adding `ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)` to the testing and validation better than not adding it?

3- Do you think there is a problem in the result of the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1 and 2: If you rescale you images, you should do it on all partitions: training, validation and test. If you only rescale your images on the training set, then your network will see very different values (0~255, vs 0.0~1.0) on validation/test set and therefore give poor accuracy. That's your case 2.
- I don't see any obvious problem.